# How to get access the ID of all posts of custom post type in Gutenberg editor

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I want to access the IDs of all posts of custom post type `book` in my custom gutenberg block `voucher` and then render them in `option list` on admin side. What i want to achieve is when i click on `voucher` block, a select tag should appear on admin editor with list of posts id of type `voucher`. I have read [Dynamic block gutenbeg](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) documentation but couldn't how i can get posts id of custom post type .

this is my code.

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('voucher/shortcode', {
    title: 'Voucher Shortcode',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        category: {
            type: 'string',
        }
    },
    edit: function(props) { 
        return  React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                    "select",
                    null,
                    React.createElement(
                    "option",
                    {
                        value: "animals"
                    },
                    "Animals"
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                    "option",
                    {
                        value: "arch"
                    },
                    "Architecture"
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                    "option",
                    {
                        value: "nature"
                    },
                    "Nature"
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                    "option",
                    {
                        value: "people"
                    },
                    "People"
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                    "option",
                    {
                        value: "tech"
                    },
                    "Tech"
                    )
                )
                );

    },
    save: function() {

          return null;
    } 
})
```

Comment: What post type you want to get in your select element as options? You talk about a list of type book and type voucher.

Comment: list of voucher @moped

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = wp.element.createElement
var withSelect = wp.data.withSelect

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('voucher/shortcode', {
title: 'Voucher Shortcode',
icon: 'smiley',
category: 'common',
attributes: {
    category: {
        type: 'string',
    }
},

edit: withSelect( function( select ) {
            var pages = select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'voucher', { per_page: -1 });

            return {
                posts: pages
            };
        } )

     (function(props) { 

            if ( ! props.posts ) {
                return "Loading...";
            }

            if ( props.posts.length === 0 ) {
                return "No posts";
            }
            var className = props.className;
            var post = props.posts[ 0 ];

            var options = [];
            var option = el(
                            'option',
                            { value: '' },
                            __('Choose')
                            );
            options.push(option);

            for (var i = 0; i < props.posts.length; i++) {
                 option = el(
                                'option',
                                { value: props.posts[i].id },
                                props.posts[i].title.raw
                                );
                options.push(option);
            }

            return [
                    el('select', {
                        onChange: onSelectVoucher,
                        },
                        options
                        )
            ]
    }),

    save: function() {

          return null;
    } })
```

You can try this for creating a dynamic select field with your CPTs voucher.  
The event-function `onChange: onSelectVoucher` is up to you what should happen.